# how can i edit the app.config file to let the application attach the database from the same folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

I'm using VS2008 with MS Sql Server 2005 to create an application.

I've used linq to query the database, and when I run the application from debug folder on my PC, it runs correctly, but when I copy the debug folder to another PC and try to run it an error message say that can not attach the database or can not find the database.

I have copied the database files into the same folder as the application DLLs, but how can I edit the config file at the debug folder to let the application attach the database from the same folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your database in a directory called `App_Data` and use the connection string like this :

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;
Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

The final folder structure of the app will be like this : bin directory contains the compiled assemblies, and in the same level as bin folder have the App_Data folder and have the database inside this App_Data folder.

Change `SQLExpress` to your database, and supply any username password etc if needed also. Look [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005) for examples of good connection strings.